# How to login with OFFLINE_ACCESS using the new Facebook PHP SDK 3.0.0?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

with the old (2.x) SDK I used this to log someone with offline_access:

```
$session = array
(
    'uid' => $userdata['fb_uid'],
    'sig' => $userdata['fb_sig'],
    'access_token' => $userdata['fb_access_token']
);

$facebook->setSession($session);
```

In the new SDK this function doesnt exist anymore. I think I need to login using:

> setPersistentData($key, $value)

but this function is protected and I dont know what 'code' is? Do I need this to log the user in or not? And what's going on with 'sig'? Don't I need this anymore?

Hope someone already figured this out because the documentation really doesn't help!

Comment: mhhh... seems like you only need to set the access_token using $facebook->setAccessToken() and that's it...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With the Facebook PHP SDK v3 ([see on github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)), it is pretty simple. To log someone with the `offline_access` permission, you ask it when your generate the login URL. Here is how you do that.

## Get the offline access token

First you check if the user is logged in or not :

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    // The access token we have is not valid
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

If he is not, you generate the "Login with Facebook" URL asking for the `offline_access` permission :

```
if (!$user) {
    $args['scope'] = 'offline_access';
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($args);
}
```

And then display the link in your template :

```
<?php if (!$user): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

Then you can retrieve the offline access token and store it. To get it, call :

```
$facebook->getAccessToken()
```

## Use the offline access token

To use the offline access token when the user is not logged in :

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$facebook->setAccessToken("...");
```

And now you can make API calls for this user :

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: This is useful, thanks, but is the PHP SDK documented somewhere other than the code?

Comment: There is no documentation for the PHP SDK in the [Facebook developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/). You can read the code, read the example provided with the SDK and find some other examples on internet. Do you need something else specific ?

Comment: How can the `offline_access` token be generated without manually logging in?

Comment: Andrew, the user has to manually log in. If the user is not logged in, ``$facebook->getAccessToken()`` will not return the access token.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP SDK 2.0 (I guess), I just use it like

```
$data = $facebook->api( '/me', 'GET', array( 'access_token' => $userdata['fb_access_token'] ) );
```

This should work with the newer one to as it seems to be more of a clean approach than rather setting up sessions by ourself. Can you try?

Answer (score 0):

Quentin's answer is pretty nice but incomplete, I think. It works nice, but I for example `getUser()` isn't working in that time because userId (which is `getUser()` returning) is cached.

I have created a new method to clear all caches and save it persistently.

```
public function setPersistentAccessToken($access_token) {
  $this->setAccessToken($access_token);
  $this->user = $this->getUserFromAccessToken();
  $this->setPersistentData('user_id', $this->user);
  $this->setPersistentData('access_token', $access_token);
  return $this;
}
```