# Keep Facebook session alive?

Tags: session, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I know there is the **offline_permission** option, but is there a way to keep the Facebook session alive?

Facebook generates the session from the stored cookie, so I am not sure, if a periodical API request renews the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `offline_access` extended permission keeps the token you receive alive. Checkout the documentation at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

> Enables your app to perform authorized requests on behalf of the user at any time. By default, most access tokens expire after a short time period to ensure applications only make requests on behalf of the user when the are actively using the application. This permission makes the access token returned by our OAuth endpoint long-lived.

You don't need to make repeat calls to keep the token active, you can just store it and use it as needed. Here's an answer that describes how to use the token with the PHP SDK: [How to login with OFFLINE_ACCESS using the new Facebook PHP SDK 3.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123859/how-to-login-with-offline-access-using-the-new-facebook-php-sdk-3-0-0/6159270#6159270)

Comment: Thank you Antonelli for your answer. So this means without the offline_access there is no way? Reason for my question is, that perhaps some people cancel the registration because of the offline_access permission. So i thought there is maybe another way. But it seems there isnt another option.

Comment: offline_access is the only way to maintain a session with a user after they have left the application. I would not recommend trying to go around this process, as I'm sure it's against Facebook's terms. (That's why they added the permission, so people can choose to allow your app to do that.)